# Java - Reading in salaries and getting total

Tags: java, file, loops, math

So basically I'm reading in some salaries from a text file and then printing them out with a "while" loop, and then I'm adding them together with another "while" loop.

My problem is that when running the code, I get the salaries read out into the console, but I don't the total salary from the second "while" loop.

The code looks like this -

```
package Week15;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class h {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("salaries.txt"));
        double items = 0;
        double total = 0;
        double salaries;

        while (scan.hasNext()){
            salaries = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(salaries);
        }   

        while (scan.hasNextDouble()) {
            // add the next salary to the total
            total += scan.nextDouble();
            // increase the number of encountered salaries by 1
            items++;
        }
        double salary = total+items;
        System.out.println("Total salary = " + salary);

        scan.close();
    }
}
```

The console looks like this -

```
14390.75
12345.99
27512.08
```

Here is the what the "salaries.txt" file I'm using looks like -

```
14390.75
12345.99
27512.08
```

Comment: Your second while loop isn't even getting executed because the scanner has already iterated over all the elements. Reset the scanner before the second loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have reached the end of file, when you exit first loop. You should again initialize

```
scan = new Scanner(new File("salaries.txt"));
```

after first loop. Your code will work.

Comment: Why read the file twice when you have already read it once and you have all the information you need? What if the file wasn't 3 lines, but 3 million lines?

Comment: you should close the Scanner before initializing a new one

Comment: You both are write, I just wanted to pinpoint the problem, without going in detail.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (scan.hasNextDouble()) {
```

This does not return true because the end of the file was reached.
Try to sum your total in the first while loop:

```
while (scan.hasNext()){
    salaries = scan.nextDouble();
    total += salaries;
    System.out.println(salaries);
}
```

You can also add your `items` count there.

Comment: Thank you, I'm very new to java and still learning, so obviously I presumed you could just run two while loops and have them work.

Answer (score 1):

You should merge the 2 loops :

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    salaries = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(salaries);

    // add the next salary to the total
    total += salaries;
    // increase the number of encountered salaries by 1
    items++;
}
```

Otherwise the first loop finishes scanning the file and you never get in the second loop as `scan.hasNextDouble()` returns false

Comment: Thank you, I have now edited my code and it works with me only needing to use one loop instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of second while loop.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("salaries.txt"));
    double items = 0;
    double total = 0;
    double salaries;

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        salaries = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(salaries);
        total += salaries;
    }

    double salary = total + items;
    System.out.println("Total salary = " + salary);

    scan.close();
```

In the first loop itself the scanner has completed all its token(element).